# sql-server-2008: running transactional log backups

Tags: sql-server-2008

When I execute a transactional log backup, does it generate EVERYTHING since the previous transactional log back up?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you run a transaction log backup, it backs up the current transaction log data and then clears the log.  Since the data will have been cleared after the last log backup, yes, it's all the transactions since the last backup.